# document.ready and asp.net page methods

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, kendo-ui

I am currently using kendo UI and ASP.NET 4.0 (non-mvc) on a project, on my project every page will have a grid that gets populated by an ajax call to a page method to that specific page.

Problem is, i cannot think of a way to not call all the grid populating functions on document.ready besides creating a seperate js file for each page. Is there a way i could have 1 page but be able to differentiate which one is being loaded and call the right grid populating page method in 1 file so this doesn't become a maintenance nightmare?

Comment: If the grid's element doesn't exist, calling the plugin on it should have no effect on your page. I would suggest though having the grid's js in a separate file, only included when needed.

Comment: Maybe you could use a single web service method instead of multiple page methods.  The method could return different things depending on the argument you would pass to it.

Answer (score 2):

Do all the grids look the same? I mean, same number of columns, same titles, same... just change the data? If so, I do recommend having a single page, a single grid and *play* with the [`DataSource`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource).

What you need is implement a [`transport.read`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportread-objectstringfunction) function and [`transport.read.data`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportreaddata-objectstringfunction) that allows you to invoke one or many `servlets` for processing the request and send different data for retrieving one or another grid's data.

Comment: they are all different, each page represents a different object which i will need to map to the grid which is where the difficulty is coming in.

Comment: Do you know beforehand what the data looks like? You can always create and destroy KendoUI grids, I don't think that you will have to do it so often so the penalty should not be that bad and much faster than load a new HTML. The idea is when you decide to load new data, issue the load, then destroy previous grid and create a new one in the same HTML position than the old one. Is that an option?

Comment: i think this is way too hard to explain, sorry .. thanks for the suggestions though